# Trying to assign a value to associative array within `eval` does not work

Tags: bash, eval, associative-array

When trying to define helper functions to build up associative lists, I get an error, I cannot resolve myself (BASH 4.4):

> /tmp/foo.sh: line 18: 'key': syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'key'")

For BASH 4.3 I got:

> /tmp/foo.sh: line 18: key: unbound variable

Here is the test case:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -u

# add services list
add_list()
{
    local list="$1"

    eval "declare -a ${list}=(); declare -A ${list}_A=()"
}

# add services to list of services
add_service()
{
    local list="$1" def="$2"
    local s="${def%%:*}"

    eval "${list}+=('$def'); ${list}_A['$s']='$def'"
}

add_list TEST
add_service TEST 'key:value'
```

The reason for the two array is that I want to access elements by key, and I want to preserve the original ordering (actually `${list}+=('$s')` would be sufficient for that).

Here is the output of `bash -x`:

```bash
> bash -x /tmp/foo.sh 
+ set -u
+ add_list TEST
+ local list=TEST
+ eval 'declare -a TEST=(); declare -A TEST_A=()'
++ TEST=()
++ declare -a TEST
++ TEST_A=()
++ declare -A TEST_A
+ add_service TEST key:value
+ local list=TEST def=key:value
+ local s=key
+ eval 'TEST+=('\''key:value'\''); TEST_A['\''key'\'']='\''key:value'\'''
++ TEST+=('key:value')
++ TEST_A['key']=key:value
/tmp/foo.sh: line 18: 'key': syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'key'")
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Unlike an assignment statement, the arguments to `declare` undergo parameter expansion before `declare` actually processes the assignment, so `list=x; declare -a $list=()` is the same as `declare -a x=()`.

Comment: @chepner I didn't know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTES:**

- skipping discussion on why `eval` may not be the best approach
- skipping discussion on an alternative approach that uses namerefs
- will focus on how OP's current code is (not) creating the desired array and a quick fix

Arrays declared in functions remain locally scoped unless the array is also declared with the `g`lobal flag; consider the following:

```
$ mytest() { typeset -a myarray; typeset -p myarray; echo "##### mytest(): exit"; }
                     ^^
$ unset myarray
$ mytest
declare -a myarray                           # array exists while inside the function
##### mytest(): exit

$ typeset -p myarray
-bash: typeset: myarray: not found           # array no longer exists once outside the function
```

Now add the `-g` flag:

```
$ mytest() { typeset -ag myarray; typeset -p myarray; echo "##### mytest(): exit"; }
                     ^^^
$ unset myarray
$ mytest
declare -a myarray                           # array exists while inside the function
##### mytest(): exit

$ typeset -p myarray
declare -a myarray                           # array still exists after leaving function
```

---

Adding the `-g` flag to *both* array declarations in OP's current function:

```
add_list()
{
    local list="$1"

    eval "declare -ag ${list}=(); declare -Ag ${list}_A=()"
    #             ^^^                     ^^^
}
```

**NOTE:** the `add_service` function definition can remain as is for now

Running OP's test:

```
$ unset TEST TEST_A
$ add_list TEST
$ add_service TEST 'key:value'
$ typeset -p TEST TEST_A
declare -a TEST=([0]="key:value")
declare -A TEST_A=([key]="key:value" )
```

---

As for why OP's current code generates an error ...

At the command prompt we'll emulate the `add_service` operation ...

```
$ unset TEST TEST_A                                       # just to make these variables are undefined before calling add_service ...

$ typeset -p TEST TEST_A                                  # verify variables are not set
-bash: typeset: TEST: not found
-bash: typeset: TEST_A: not found

$ TEST+=('key:value')                                     # bash recognizes this as valid array syntax and will automagically create a normal (-a) array named TEST
$ typeset -p TEST
declare -a TEST=([0]="key:value")

$ TEST_A['key']='key:value'                               # bash recognizes this as the correct syntax for an integer-keyed array but has problems processing the string `key` as an integer so ...
-bash: 'key': syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'key'")

$ TEST_A[key]='key:value'                                 # again, looks like correct syntax but in this case no error ...
$ typeset -p TEST_A
declare -a TEST_A=([0]="key:value")
        ^^

        # in this case bash considers key as a variable (ie, bash treats it as $key)
        # but since $key is undefined it defaults to 0 and a normal array (-a) is
        # created with index 0

$ TEST_A[xxx]='keyX:valueX'
$ typeset -p TEST_A
declare -a TEST_A=([0]="keyX:valueX")                     # $xxx is undefined, treated as 0, and we end up overwriting previous 0-indexed entry in array

$ key=9
$ TEST_A[key]='key:value'
$ typeset -p TEST_A
declare -a TEST_A=([0]="keyX:valueX" [9]="key:value")     # $key is defined (9) so we get a new array entry with index=9
```

Comment: To summarize: `declare` made the new arrays *local*, but the effect only showed for the array `TEST_A` being expected to be associative, when in fact it was not. Adding `-g` when declaring was sufficient to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using `declare` in a function makes the variable local, so it's probably impossible to convert a local variable to an associative array by calling a custom function.

For a normal array it's possible though, check the result of this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

make_it_an_array() {
    [[ $1 =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*$ ]] || return 1
    eval "$1=()"
}

fun1() {
    local arr # arr isn't an array, so what will happen?
    make_it_an_array arr
    printf '"%s" in %s: %s\n' "$1" "$FUNCNAME" "$(declare -p arr 2> /dev/null)"
}

#############################################################

fun1 arr
printf '"arr" in main: %s\n' "$(declare -p arr 2> /dev/null)"
```

```
"arr" in fun1: declare -a arr='()'
"arr" in main:
```

If you replace `eval "$1=()"` with `declare -ga "$1=()"` the result will be:

```
"arr" in fun1: declare -a arr='()'
"arr" in main: declare -a arr='()'
```

which means that the local scope of the variable in the parent function has been lost.

---

**Aside:**

If `$list` only contains the name of a variable then you can replace:

```bash
eval "declare -a ${list}=(); declare -A ${list}_A=()"
```

With:

```bash
declare -a "$list=()"
declare -A "${list}_A=()"
```

Comment: Support for `declare -g` to create global variables from inside a function was added to `bash` 4.2.

Comment: @chepner That's right, but `declare -g` reaches the global scope even if the variable is local in the parent scope, that's what my answer is about. I might have expressed it incorrectly